# Socket c++: recv function returns -1

Tags: c++, c, sockets, winsock2, recv

I'm trying to code a simple android client communicating with a windows server.
I'm using sockets to achieve that and up to now, I was testing everything with a Linux machine (android client and linux server). So far, everything was working. Now i'm trying to set it up on windows (the server) and I have of course noticed that I had to change my code a little (if not just the include ^^').
Anyway, my problem is that my recv functions returns -1 while it should read something but it doesn't for some reason.

Below is how I use my recv function (EDIT: the whole server code now):

```
int tcp_server::start_listening()
{

    WORD wVersionRequested;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int wsaerr;
    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    wsaerr = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);
    if (wsaerr != 0)
    {
        printf("Server: The Winsock dll not found!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

   else
    {
        printf("Server: The Winsock2 dll found \n");
    }

    sSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if(sSock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Server: Error initializing socket!n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }


    sockaddr_in service,client ;
    service.sin_family = AF_INET;
    service.sin_port = htons(port);
    service.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;


   if(bind(sSock,(SOCKADDR*)&service,sizeof(service))==SOCKET_ERROR)
   {
       printf("Server: Error binding socket to portn");
       WSACleanup();
       return 0;
   }

   /* wait for incoming connections */
   if(listen(sSock,10)==SOCKET_ERROR)
       printf("listen(): Error listening on socket %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
   else
   {
      printf("Server: Waiting for connections...\n");
   }

   /* accept connections */
   AcceptSocket;
   printf("Server: Waiting for a client to connect...\n");
   AcceptSocket = accept(sSock, NULL, NULL);
   if (AcceptSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
       wprintf(L"accept failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
       closesocket(sSock);
       WSACleanup();
       return 1;
   } else {
       wprintf(L"Client connected.\n");
       acceptConns();
   }

   closesocket(sSock);
   return 0;
}
int tcp_server::acceptConns()
{
    sockaddr_in from;
    bool infinite = true ;
    int fromlen=sizeof(from);
    int readsize;
    char* message;
    char* clientmessage = "\0";
    string smatrix ;
    int ind ;
    string tok;
    int i = 0 ;
    int bytesSent ;

    float matrix[16] ;
    while( (readsize = recv(AcceptSocket, clientmessage, 2000, 0))!= 0 ){
        message = "ack";
        cout << "Writing ACK" << endl ;
        smatrix = clientmessage ;
        std::stringstream ss(smatrix);

        cout << smatrix << endl ;
        while(getline(ss, tok, ',') && i < 16 ){
            matrix[i] = static_cast<float>(::atof(tok.c_str()));
            i++ ;
        }
        i = 0 ;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    if(readsize == 0 ){
        cerr << "client disconnected" << endl ;
    }
    cout << "Socket closed" << endl ;
    closesocket(sSock);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

As for my android code: here it is:

```
 while(closeConnection == false) {
        if (connected == true && matrixupdated == true && this.hasMatrixChanged()){
            try {
                //= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(java.lang.System.in));
                DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                String sentence = this.getStringFromMatrix();
                outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + "\n");
                outToServer.flush();
                inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                System.arraycopy(matrix, 0, previousMatrix, 0, 16);
                inFromServer.read(serverMsg);
                if(serverMsg.equals("ack") == true){
                    this.serverHasInput = false ;
                    Log.e("ACK", "ACK");
                    inFromServer.read(serverMsg);       //Wait for the "ok" message from server
                    if(serverMsg.equals("ok") == false){
                        Log.e("ERROR IN COM W/ SERV"," DID NOT RECEIVE OK");
                    }
                }
                else{
                    this.serverHasInput = true ;
                }
                //Log.d("SERVERMSG", "DONE WAITING");

            }catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);
            }
            this.matrixupdated = false ;
        }

    }
    try {
        outToServer.flush();
        outToServer.close();
        inFromServer.close();
        clientSocket.close();
    }
```

Finally the output I get in the console is unfortunately

> client disconnected

I'm guessing this is probably some really dumb stuff, but i've been trying to see on MS website and the documentation of recv why it would give me -1 but I can't get my hands on a explanation.

Thanks in advance for the help provided :).

Comment: OK, what is the result of WSAGetLastError() when the syscall fails?

Comment: 'trying to see on MS website and the documentation of recv why it would give me -1 but I can't get my hands on a explanation' REALLY???    MSDN: If no error occurs, recv returns the number of bytes received and the buffer pointed to by the buf parameter will contain this data received. If the connection has been gracefully closed, the return value is zero.

Otherwise, a value of SOCKET_ERROR is returned, and a specific error code can be retrieved by calling WSAGetLastError.'

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP did not read the MSDN documentation for the failed syscall.

Comment: The -1 returned by the function is still not explained, even when I do call GetLastError. Don't close the question for that cause I did read. Anyway, GetLastError gives me 10057 which is client is not connected, but when testing my code with a Linux server, the client is connected.

Comment: Also, your buffer 'char* clientmessage = "\0";' is a string literal which, as well as being too short to acommodate 2000 chars, is read-only and will cause the recv() to fail.

Comment: Also, what is the 'Sleep(1000);' for?

Comment: You can get rid of it, it was there for testing purposes afterwards as the input I'll get from the client I need to check it out

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem with the client message variable, though it was not the origin of the problem as i'm sure you know

Comment: This line `cout << recv(sSock, clientmessage, 2000, 0) << endl ;` in your server code could potentially read everything leaving nothing for the next statement `while( (readsize = recv(sSock, clientmessage, 2000, 0))!= 0 )`. On entry to while loop, `readsize` will then be set to 0 if there are nothing left to receive, hence the `client disconnected` output.

Comment: That may indeed have caused problem so I changed it but that was not the reason behind my problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many errors in the C++ code - like `if (bytesSent = 0)`, which is an assignment with result cast to boolean, so always returning `false`. You don't pay attention to number of bytes read from a TCP socket, assuming that you receive one complete message as you sent it - this is wrong since you might be reading a partial message, more then one message, or anything in between - **it is a raw byte stream**.

Check for `-1` returned from system calls explicitly, and then examine the value of `errno(3)`, with say, `strerror(3)` function to figure out what went wrong.

#### Edit 0:

You are trying to use the listening socket `sSock` for data transfer - wrong - it is only there for accepting client connection requests. Use `AcceptedSocket`, the one returned from `accept()`. It is the connection to the client.

Comment: You're completely right ^^'. Will change my code ASAP

Comment: I can I possibly check for the correct number of bytes then? Also, I'm not sure about the way to use strerror(3) but when I do I get no such process. Thanks for the answer so far and the help you've provided

Comment: On Windows use [GetLastError https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx] and lookup the return value on MSDN.

Comment: Oh then I did already :). So I get 10057 which is Socket is not connected. However I don't fully understand why I get it. Will look back at my client code again (the android one) and see if that still works with the linux server

Comment: You probably need to call `WSAStartup()` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to initialize winsock library. And please do check return code of `connect()` :)

Comment: Just re-tested the client with the linux server and everything works just fine :). Will try to do what you suggest and update my question with the results then. But connecting works fine as I do detect the connection first before it closes

Comment: Indeed just re-checked and connect works just fine. I did use WSAStartup but it doesn't change the output and I still have the same kind of error. My client is still up and running and it still works with a  linux server. So i'm guessing something's wrong with my server code i just can't understand what

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov: to get socket error codes, use `WSAGetLastError()` instead of `GetLastError()`.  And if `WSAStartup()` were not called, winsock functions would be failing with error code 10093 (`WSANOTINITIALISED`).

Comment: @LonniBesançon: yes, please show the server code that is initializing `sSock` before calling `recv()` on it.

Comment: Remy, you're right, thanks. It's been a long while since I messed with sockets on Windows.

Comment: Edit solved my problem. Now I still get empty messages from the client but I'm guessing it's an other error in my server code. Thanks a lot for the help (PS: if you have any idea of where this could come from feel free to say so ^^')

Comment: Actually no the problem is not solved, looks like I still get less than 0 from recv. Sorry for such a late update

Answer (score 1):

The client socket that you should be reading/writing to is the 'AcceptSocket' that is returned by the Accept() call, Not the 'sSock' server socket!

Either move the declaration of AcceptSocket to a member var, pass it to 'acceptConns();' as a parameter or start a thread to run acceptConns, passing the AcceptSocket as the void* parameter to pthread_create, (or whatever).

I think that both Remy and I strongly suspected that this was your problem even before you posted the Accept code:)

Ohwait - Nikloai's edit got in first - upvote him!

Comment: Indeed you were right about that, it does partially solve my problem. Now still have to figure why I get an empty message from the client (I'm sure something is sent so it does come from the server again ^^') :)

Comment: In the end as mentioned above that did not solve my problem as I still get less than 0

Comment: Did you fix the 'clientmessage = "\0";' issue?

Comment: Mebbe you should post a new question with your latest code, new problem/s and debugging results.  Editing your original question does not provide a good Q&A resource for future SO users - it will force them to plough though edits and just confuse them:(

Comment: Damn it, when going back to a previous version of my code I didn't pay attention to the fact that the fixed client_message was not fixed anymore. Thanks a lot for the help anyway. So I guess both you and Nikolai were right, any way to give you both credits? :)